# Parsing multiple formats of values to give a true quantity with regex

Tags: r, regex

I am currently parsing a large data set of drug prescriptions in R, because these have been collected manually (at least that's my guess) the data is extraordinarily messy and painful to deal with, because there's no consistency to the way it has been collated.

My specific issue is that I need to extract the quantity of drugs which have been prescribed so that I can subsequently match them for downstream analysis. However, just to give you a taste of what these can look like:

```
quantity
28 capsules
28
84
28.000
3 millilitres
200 tablet
1 pack of 28 tablet(s)
3*1 mcg
2*91 tablets
2*200 grams
3*112 tablet - Tutti Frutti
Tibolone 2.5mg tablets 3*28 tablet
```

Some of these prescriptions will be made for the same drug, just by different doctors, so there's absolutely no consistency to how they're entered.

As I want to try and get the true quantity of the drugs prescribed I have been **TRYING** to extract that based on a few rules in R:

```
### Find prescriptions which are multiples (e.g. "2 packs of 10 pills" or "2*10 pills")

gp_prescriptions$multiples_status = grepl(" of ", gp_prescriptions$quantity) | grepl("\\*", gp_prescriptions$quantity)

### Create simple column for extracting numbers

gp_prescriptions$basic_column = as.numeric(gp_prescriptions$quantity)

gp_prescriptions$simple_column = gsub("[[:alpha:]]+|[[:punct:]]", "", gp_prescriptions$quantity)
gp_prescriptions$simple_column = gsub("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)", "_", gp_prescriptions$simple_column, perl = TRUE)
```

Here my logic is as follows:

If there is only a number in the column (e.g. `28`) this becomes the `basic_column`

If instead there are multiple numbers, I try and remove all letters and punctuation so that I get something like this `1_28`. This has the unfortunate consequence of also removing `.` though so I get numbers like `28000` as a value for something which should be `28`, but I'm hoping the existence of the `basic_column` will allow me to overcome that.

What I then want to do is based on the first line, which finds rows that have "multiples" is I want to calculate the value of `2*91` (or whatever). However, I can't just do this based on it **usually** being the first 2 numbers in the column, so what I need to do is do something like finding the two numbers on either side of " of " or "*" and then multiply those. But I have absolutely no idea how to even get started with this.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas for how I can deal with this? Or am I going about this in a ridiculous way in the first place?